ConnectTimeoutError to api.vk.com
Я открыл доступ со своего сервера до api.vk.com по 443 порту, пытаюсь выполнить этот код:
def main():
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=config.bot_token)
    vk = vk_session.get_api()
    longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

получаю ошибку:
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='im.vk.com', port=443):
Read timed out. (read timeout=35)

при этом сетевые доступы есть:
> telnet im.vk.com 443
Trying 93.186.237.7...
Connected to im.vk.com.

> telnet api.vk.com 443
Trying 93.186.225.205...
Connected to api.vk.com.

но....
> openssl s_client -connect api.vk.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 302 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---

Я плохо разбираюсь в Linux. Может кто-то сталкивался с данной проблемой и подскажет решение

перечисленные вами имена резолвятся в кучу разных ip-адресов. причём наверняка список этот димнамически меняется. открывайте лучше всё.

я по доменному имени открыл порты

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')) такая ошибка осталась
